# Catch SELECT change in Dynamic SELECT ID

Tags: jquery

I have a table that have several selects inside with dynamic generated ID's.

Something like this:
`<select id="Select_1">...`
`<select id="Select_2">...`
`<select id="Select_3">...`

Is there a way that i can catch everytime one of the select's change?

I've tried several ways like:
`$("select").change`
`$("#Select_").change`
`$("select#Select_").change`

None of them worked...

Any help?

Comment: `$("select").change` should work (but not the others). You could also give each select a class the refer to the class.

Comment: `$("select").change` doesn't work by itself, show more code

Comment: This doesn't work? `$("select").change(function(){console.log(this.id+' changed.')});`

Comment: When are you dynamically generating the selects? If you're generating them after the page loads you might need to delegate

Comment: works fine here http://jsfiddle.net/wirey00/WzfXg/

Comment: In fact, the codes are generated after the page is loaded, via AJAX.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$(document).on('change', 'select', function (event) {

  // your code here
  // `this` scope is pointing to current select which value was changed

  $(this).val() // get selected value
  $(this).attr('id') // or this.id - current ID

});
```

I have hope it will help you to start with.

Comment: This solution worked but the problem is that i have a lot of others select's that i don't want to catch. With this solution i'll catch every select change and i have make some code in order to check if is the correct select.

Comment: This code works fine. Inside the function i've added the following code: if ($(this).hasClass('selectClassName')) and it worked just fine.

Answer (score 0):

Give select element a common class, and use the class to call change:

HTML:

```
<select class="sel" id="select_1">
<option value="y">Yellow</option>
<option value="b">Blue</option>
</select>
<br/>
<select class="sel" id="select_2">
<option value="g">Green</option>
<option value="r">Red</option>
</select>
```

JQuery:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.sel').change(function(){
        alert($(this).find('option:selected').val());
    });
});
```